# PHP Page Stuck at Loading while Another PHP script is running

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to web development and trying to set up a site with multiple PHP pages and MySQL connection.

I just found out that if my page1.php is running, and I try to open page2.php, page2.php will get stuck at loading, nothing will show.

In the case of page1.php it takes a long time to finish (it iterates through a database and does some updates), page2.php will show nothing but a black page until a Gateway Time Out error occurs. This will happen even if I close page1.php, it seems the script on page1.php is running in the background anyway until it's done.

Can anyone tell me what might be the problem? Some configuration issue on the php.ini maybe?

Comment: Is your `page2.php` trying to query the same database table/rows that you're updating in `page1.php`? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15872494/3794472

Comment: You need to look into session blocking, to resolve this you will use  `session_write_close()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is session locking the session store file:

1. page1.php: `session_start()` locks the session file.
2. page2.php: `session_start()` blocks on the session file.
3. page1.php: finishes it's long processing, calls `session_write_close()` either explicitly or implicitly
4. page2.php: `session_start()` unblocks and can continue

The remedy is to call `session_write_close()` before any long activity. If you need to save data to session when page1.php finishes, call `session_start()` again.

Comment: The OP made no mention of even using sessions.

Comment: @MikeBrant most of the time people don't even realize they are using sessions but this is the main cause of this error.